# Send a command to a device offering a serial port profile over bluetooth

Tags: c, bluetooth

I am trying to develop an app in C which should send some command to a device 
in order make it send some previously stored data over Bluetooth. I got an example from windows SDK and tried to change it.

For example to shutdown the device the command is supposed to be like this :

```
 const char Cmd_Shutdown[]=  {0xFC,00,0xFF,00,0xcf,0x63,0xFD};
```

I don't know why but it is not working. Each of those hex number must be of one byte.

I tried sending it like this:

```
 SOCKET_ERROR == send(LocalSocket,
                      Cmd_Shutdown,
                      sizeof(Cmd_Shutdown),
                      0) )
```

FC and FD are start and stop byte and cf63 is the crc result.

Please can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have the wrong endianness?  Try sending the command in the reverse endian.